# Size method of QVector and std::vector

Tags: c++, qt, types, vector

The size method of `QVector` is of type `int`, but the same method in `std::vector` is `unsigned`. Why is the difference. Isn't unsigned type the right way to hold size, since it can't be negative?

Comment: 0 is still a valid size, in some cases you might want to have something like -1 to signify an invalid

Comment: Also, the common practice is to use an `int` in loops, so if you compare an int to a uint you get compiler warnings. There is not that significant shortcoming to be limited to only half the size of a unsigned int.

Comment: @ddriver People are usually surprised because it goes against the STL's ubiquitous use of `size_t`, rather than any practical or logical reason.

Comment: What would an invalid size container be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [they discussed it in 1999](http://web.archive.org/web/20070222073355/http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/1999-03/thread00251-0.html) and got to the conclusion that `int` is a better choice, since the number of functions returning `uint` was relatively small and they were displeased by the warnings:

> ```
> Subject: Re: killing uint as return type in Qt.
> From: Alex Sandro Queiroz e Silva <asandro@xxxxxxxxxxxxx>
> Date: Wed, 17 Mar 1999 15:29:37 -0300 (EST)
> Cc: qt-interest@xxxxxxxx
> To: Arnt Gulbrandsen <arnt@xxxxxxxx>
> ```
>
> On 17 Mar 1999, Arnt Gulbrandsen wrote:
>
> > About 0.15% of the functions in Qt return uint.  Most of those are
> >     called QMumble::size() or QMumble::count().  These functions never
> >     need to return a negative number, so really, uint is the right type
> >     for them to return.
> >
> > But it's a nuisance, to me at least. I keep comparing them with ints,
> >     putting them in variables that -can- contain negative numbers, and so
> >     on.  I've written
> >
> > ```
> >  if ( blah->count() < i )
> > ```
> >
> > and gotten compiler warning too many times already.
> >
> > So I am considering changing the return type for these functions to
> >     int in Qt 2.0.  What do you think?  You're the users - do you want
> >     correctness and total backward compatibility or would you prefer more
> >     convenience?
> >
> > --Arnt
>
> I think this time convenience is better, we all now the kind of
>   results we may get from this methos, so...
>
> -- Alex       asandro@lcg.dc.ufc.br

Comment: rubenvb: Why stupid? (FWIW I thought about it now and based on my intervening java experience, I think it was the right choice. Uint is well-intentioned, but java shows that it's not very helpful in practice.)

Comment: @arnt: Wait. Are you _the arnt_ I quoted? Woah. That being said I guess rubenvb likes correct types for correct circumstances. There's no way`*::size()` will ever produce a negative value. On the other hand, even Haskell's `length :: [a] -> Int` doesn't use the unsigned type `Word`, so there are decisions based convenience all the time. (Also, do you have a mirror of the mailing list?)

Comment: I am that arnt, yes, and I like to reconsider decisions like this and try to learn. IMO size() is restricted to something much less than merely [0,UINT_MAX], it's restricted to [0,x], where x is the number of objects one can malloc, perhaps 5-10% of UINT_MAX if malloc is space-effective, the objects very small and pointers are wide as integers. This means that the return value of size() fits in the shared subset of int and uint, and both types are equally appropriate. After all, one should use the smallest type that fully spans the possible values, and int and uint both meet that test.

Comment: And I'm afraid I don't have a mirror anywhere. But you can find a mirror of the old source on my github account.